# PHP MySQL joins and outputting as array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

I was wondering if someone could help me please.

I have the following two tables, positions and polygons.

```
positions:
----------------------------------------------
| positionID | name        | information
----------------------------------------------
| 1          | Southampton | text here
| 2          | London      | text here
```

.

```
polygons:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| polygonID | positionID | lat           | lon
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 1          | 434343.034343 | -43.4343434
| 2         | 1          | 343343.034343 | -43.4343434
| 3         | 1          | 434343.034343 | -54.4343434
```

I want to join the two tables and output them as an array in the following format.

```
$positions = array(
               array( positionID => 1, 
                      name => 'Southampton',
                      information => 'text here',
                      polys =>  array( array( Lat => 54.54299483853406, 
                                      Lng => -6.5224456787109375,
                                     ),
                                array( Lat => 54.648809788121866, 
                                       Lng => -6.405029296875,
                                     ),
                                array( Lat => 54.54020652089137, 
                                       Lng => -6.39129638671875,
                                     ),
                                ),
               ),
       );
```

I have wrote the following join statement however I'm really stuck on the next step.

```
SELECT * FROM (`positions`) LEFT JOIN `polygons` ON `positions`.`positionID` = `positions`.`positions`
```

The lat/lon data from the joins must be stored on the 'polys' key in the array.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one polygonID per positionID, you going to fetch a lot of copies of positions.
I recommend to do 2 queries instead:

```
$positions = array();

$query_1 = "SELECT * FROM positions";
$query_2 = "SELECT * FROM polygons";

$resource_1 = mysql_query($query_1);

while($position = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource_1))
{
    $positions[$position['positionID']] = $position;
    $positions[$position['positionID']]['polys'] = array();
}

$resource_2 = mysql_query($query_2);

while($polygon = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource_2))
{
    $positions[$polygon['positionID']]['polys'][$polygon['polygonID']]['Lat'] = $polygon['lat'];
    $positions[$polygon['positionID']]['polys'][$polygon['polygonID']]['Lon'] = $polygon['lon'];
}
```

(Sorry for using deprecated functions like mysql_query in my exemple)

Comment: Thanks for that?  I was wondering which is more efficient for this sort of thing, one query or two queries?

Answer (score 0):

You only need one query, but you still need to do some processing with the result in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM positions
    LEFT JOIN polygons ON positions.positionID = polygons.positionID";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $positions = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (!isset($positions[$row['name']])) {
            $positions[$row['name']] = array(
                'positionID' => $row['positionID'],
                'information' => $row['information'],
                'polys' => array()
                );
        }
        $positions[$row['name']]['polys'][] = array(
            'lat' => $row['lat'],
            'lon' => $row['lon']
            );
    }

    print_r($positions);
}
```

This will also return positions which don't actually have any polygon information.  To prevent that, simply change the `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

As for which is most efficient, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that. Best bet is to benchmark both this method and the one advised by Puggan Se if you can.